# run apps script based on first column value

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, checkbox

completely new to Apps script; I did not find anything on the web, so please forgive me if it was already asked.

I have a spreadsheet in which, in the first column, there are checkboxes that can be true or false. I would like to run a script only on the rows that have the true checkbox. Here's the script (which is not running, it is just returning the first row).

```
function prova() {
    const modello = DriveApp.getFileById('XXXX');
    const cartellaword = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXX');
    const cartellapdf = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXX');
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('automazione');
    const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

    rows.forEach(function(row, column) {
      if (column[0] = true) {
        const copy = modello.makeCopy(`${row[1]} - prova`, cartellaword);
        const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
        const body = doc.getBody();
        const oggi = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy");
        const pdf = doc.getAs(MimeType.PDF);

        body.replaceText('{oggi}', oggi);
        body.replaceText('{nome}', row[1]);
        body.replaceText('{datanascita}', row[2]);

        doc.saveAndClose();
        cartellapdf.createFile(pdf).setName(`${row[1]} - prova`)
      }
    })
}
```

I tried to use:

```
if (column[0] === true { /// run script } 
if (index[0] = true { /// run script }
```

Right now, the script works but it creates a PDF replacing only the first row (cell A1 is empty).
I expected it to work for every rows which first cell (B1, C1, D1...) has the true checkbox.

Comment: A single equals sign is an assignment not a comparison operator

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this `if (column[0] = true) {` to this `if (column[0] == true) {`

also the second parameter of a forEach is an index and in this case it will be the same as row number minus one so it is not an array so column[0] makes no sense.

References:

[Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 0):

I did it with two equals: no script errors but it does not generate any document.
I did not understand the part in which you say that "column[0] makes no sense"...
Anyway, is there a way in which I can autofill a template document basing on a sheet in which I can choose the rows?
Previously, I run this script:

```
rows.forEach(function(row, index) {
if (index === 0) return;
```

then the rest is the same. In this way the script used only the rows that were not empty (with the exception of the first one, with headers: perfect but I did not understand how!). Now I would like to being able to choose which rows will be run by the script.
Hope I was clear...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!
The script is:

```
rows.forEach(function(row) {
if (row[0] == true) {
const copy .... //the rest is the same.
```